# How to fix "Error in attr(data, "tsp") <- c(start, end, frequency) : object is not a matrix" in linear regression time series analysis?

Tags: r, statistics, time-series, data-science

Trying to fit a linear model with time series components in R: tslm(y ~ trend + season)

I have y, trend and season in the form of time series matrices. The y, trend and season data are `value_1_ts`, `trendcycle(fit_1)` and `seasonal(fit_1)` respectively.

The data look like this:

[image]

My r code looks like this:

```
ts(value_1_ts ~ trendcycle(fit_1) + seasonal(fit_1))
```

The error I get looks like this:

```
{r}
ts(value_1_ts ~ trendcycle(fit_1) + seasonal(fit_1))
```

I'm not sure what I should do next.

Comment: Please fix the question. Your r code chunks appear to be incomplete. It would also help if you provided code that reproduced the problem.